# How Can I Check To See If A Variable Exists In An Array?

Tags: php, arrays

I have a flat file called data.txt. Each line contains four entries.

data.txt

```
blue||green||purple||primary
green||yellow||blue||secondary
orange||red||yellow||secondary
purple||blue||red||secondary
yellow||red||blue||primary
red||orange||purple||primary
```

And I tried this to find out if the variable "yellow" exists as the FIRST entry on any of the lines:

```
$color = 'yellow';

$a = array('data.txt');

 if (array_key_exists($color,$a)){
 // If true
   echo "$color Key exists!";
   } else {
 // If NOT true
   echo "$color Key does not exist!";
   }
```

but it is not working as expected. What can I change to get this going? Thanks....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following utilizes [`preg_grep`](http://php.net/preg_grep), which performs a regular expression search on each element of an array (in this case, the lines of the file):

```
$search = 'yellow';
$file = file('file.txt');

$items = preg_grep('/^' . preg_quote($search, '/') . '\|\|/', $file);

if(count($items) > 0)
{
   // found
}
```

Comment: Though that would false positive match any prefix of other words.  If the example is just contrived.  ie. `$search = 'yell'` would match `yellow` as the first word, a change to the regex would be required to ensure a separator followed or a line terminal.

Comment: @Orbling: Thanks for that overlook. Updated.

Answer (score 0):

```
$fh = fopen("data.txt","r");
$color = 'yellow';
$test = false;

while( ($line = fgets($fh)) !== false){
    if(strpos($line,$color) === 0){
        $test = true;
        break;
    }
}

fclose($fh);
// Check $test to see if there is a line beginning with yellow
```

Answer (score 0):

The data in your file is not loaded into `$a`. Try

```
$a = explode("\n", file_get_contents('data.txt'));
```

to load it and then check each line with:

```
$line_num = 1;
foreach ($a as $line) {
   $entries = explode("||", $line);
   if (array_key_exists($color, $entries)) {
      echo "$color Key exists! in line $line_num";
   } else {
      echo "$color Key does not exist!";
   }
   ++$line_num;
}
```

Comment: This code displays: Warning: explode() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in /www/tests/mobilestimulus/array_tests/index1.php on line 10 Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /www/tests/mobilestimulus/array_tests/index1.php on line 13

Comment: @mobilestimulus I wrote this code without testing it. I missed the first argument delimiter ("\n" - the new line character) of the first explode. It should work properly now.

Answer (score 0):

The line:

```
$a = array('data.txt');
```

Only creates an array with one value in it: 'data.txt'.  You need to read and parse the file first before checking for the values.

Answer (score 0):

Well, that's not how you load a separated list of data from a text file in to an array.

Also `array_key_exists()` checks keys only, not the values of an array.

Try:

```
$lines = file('data.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);

$firstEntries = array();

foreach ($lines as $cLine) {
   $firstEntries[] = array_shift(explode('||', $cLine));
}

$colour = 'yellow';

if (in_array($colour, $firstEntries)) {
   echo $colour . " exists!";
} else {
   echo $colour . " does not exist!";
}
```

Comment: This code will return "exists' even if yellow is NOT the first entry on the line.

Comment: @mobilestimulus: Didn't notice the "FIRST" constraint, I'll update it.